# Registry key "protocols" empty

Tags: windows, windows-registry, tls

Im checking a windows 2019 server and the key "protocols" is empty

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols
```

On my Windows 10 also is empty.

This means by default is using tls 1.2?

I asked because i have lanweeper app and log have this info:

Default TLS for Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0: Enabled SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server key does not exist.

SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings key found for LocalMachine. SecureProtocols value does not exist.

SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings key found for CurrentUser (IIS APPPOOL\Lansweeper AppPool: S-1-5-82-3613481208-1942224173-2920386345-3998730154-4078748822). SecureProtocols value does not exist. TlsEnabled: True

Answer (score 0):

All the subkeys under the SCHANNEL key are empty, because they all have
defaults. They are only populated when you wish to override these defaults.

Actually, there is no "default" TLS version, because the TLS version is
negotiated with the web-server. If a protocol is enabled, then it can be
used after negotiation.

The enabled TLS version are dependent on the Windows version used.
The table below resumes which Windows 10 versions support which TLS
versions as either client or server.

| Windows OS | TLS 1.0 Client | TLS 1.0 Server | TLS 1.1 Client | TLS 1.1 Server | TLS 1.2 Client | TLS 1.2 Server | TLS 1.3 Client | TLS 1.3 Server |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Windows 10, version 1507 | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Not supported | Not supported |
| Windows 10, version 1511 | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Not supported | Not supported |
| Windows 10, version 1607/Windows Server 2016 Standard | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Not supported | Not supported |
| Windows 10, version 1703 | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Not supported | Not supported |
| Windows 10, version 1709 | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Not supported | Not supported |
| Windows 10, version 1803 | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Not supported | Not supported |
| Windows 10, version 1809//Windows Server 2019 | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Not supported | Not supported |
| Windows 10, version 1903 | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Not supported | Not supported |
| Windows 10, version 1909 | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Not supported | Not supported |
| Windows 10, version 2004 | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Not supported | Not supported |
| Windows 10, version 20H2 | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Not Supported | Not Supported |
| Windows 10, version 21H1 | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Not Supported | Not Supported |
| Windows 10, version 21H2 | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Not Supported | Not Supported |
| Windows Server 2022 | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled |
| Windows 11 | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled | Enabled |

References:

- [Protocols in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-)
- [Managing SSL/TLS Protocols and Cipher Suites for AD FS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/manage-ssl-protocols-in-ad-fs)

Comment: Add this to your post - it's unreadable this way.